# CODESYS, TON not resetting

Tags: plc, codesys

I have an INT and TON defined

```
VAR
    state : INT := 0;
    timer_on : TON;
END_VAR
```

Now. The program is like this

```
IF (state = 0) THEN
    timer_on(IN := TRUE, PT := T#5s);

    IF (timer_on.Q = TRUE) THEN
        timer_on.IN := FALSE;
        state := 1;
    END_IF
END_IF
```

When it is executed state is changed to 0 after 5 seconds. That's ok. But when I change state back to 0 it immediately goes back to 1. According to the documentation

> Q is TRUE when IN is TRUE and ET is equal to PT. Otherwise it is FALSE.

In my case, after 5 seconds Q is always TRUE even when IN is FALSE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the input variables of a function block does **NOT** execute the function block. You need to run it to see the change.

What happens when you run your program:

1. state is 0, so first IF is entered
2. timer_on is started for 5 seconds
3. after 5 seconds, state is still 0 and timer_on.Q becomes true, so second if is also entered.
4. timer_on.IN is set to false, **but timer_on is not executed**, state is also set to 1
5. state is 1 so code is skipped
6. after state is set to 0 manually, the first if is enered. timer_on is run with IN true, but because this timer was **never** reset, it immidiately finishes.

The solution is to change the `timer_on.IN := FALSE;` line to `timer_on(IN := FALSE);`. This will run the timer with IN false which, as the documentation states, will reset itself for the next use.